# How do I improve model accuracy predicting categorical outcome using categorial predictors?

Tags: categorical-data, prediction, scikit-learn, pandas

I'm trying to predict `Para` using `Col`s. My data is in this format:

```
Record ID Para  Col2     Col3
1          A        x      a
1          A        x      b
2          B        y      a
2          B        y      b
1          A        z      c
1          C        x      a
```

So far, I have tried applying One Hot Encoding (OHE) and running algorithms on the following transformed data:

```
Record Para  a     b      c    x   y  z 
1       A    1     1      1    1   0  1
1       C    1     1      1    1   0  1
2       B    1     1      0    0   1  0
```

The accuracy has been shoddy, highest of 27% with Logistic Regression. I tried kNN, Random Forest, Decision Tree.

Next, I tried encoding the `Col`s to ordinal variables and then reran the algorithms (except Logistic Regression). Similarly poor results.

Am I doing something incorrectly? How can I improve the accuracy?

The raw data is `249681 rows × 9 columns`. Both outcome and predictor columns are categorical. When doing OHE, the data is `5534 rows × 865 columns`.

One thing that I'd like to try is Naive Bayes that calculates P(Outcome|Predictor) and then assign the highest probability predictor to the outcome. Is that a reasonable approach to take?

Comment: The example data is not one-hot encoded. Columns of a one-hot encoded feature are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Additionally, what does it mean for multiple rows to have the same record ID? Is there structure in your data?

Comment: The columns are mutually exclusive. Where do you see repetition?

Yes, that's the structure of the data. A record can have multiple `Para`s. For each para, the values of the columns `a` through `z` are duplicated. I'd like the model to be able to predict both `A` and `C` for record 1.